# Optional arguments in getopt

Tags: perl

I'm trying to use `getopt` from `Getopt::Std` for multiple arguments. I have `getopt('s:il');` where I want `s` to be a mandatory search word, `i` to be an optional integer, and `l` to be an optional letter.  This is working when I use all 3, but if I add `'-s search -i -l g'` to my command line, I get the result `-l` in my variable for `i`, instead of Perl recognizing `-i` as blank and `'g'` as an argument for `l`. Is there a way around this? Do I need to use an alternate getopt(s) command?

Answer (score 2):

Use the [getopts](http://perldoc.perl.org/Getopt/Std.html) function instead of `getopt`:

```
use warnings;
use strict;
use Getopt::Std;

my %opts;
getopts('s:il', \%opts);

use Data::Dumper;
$Data::Dumper::Sortkeys=1;
print Dumper(\%opts);

__END__

my_script.pl -s foo -i -l

$VAR1 = {
          'i' => 1,
          'l' => 1,
          's' => 'foo'
        };
```